# Sed range and removing last matching line

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have this data:

```
One
  two
  three
Four
  five
  six
Seven
  eight
```

And this command:

```
sed -n '/^Four$/,/^[^[:blank:]]/p'
```

I get the following output:

```
Four
  five
  six
Seven
```

How can I change this sed expression to not match the final line of the output? So the ideal output should be:

```
Four
  five
  six
```

I've tried many things involving exclamation points but haven't managed to get close to getting this working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may pipe to another `sed` and skip last line:

```
sed -n '/^Four$/,/^[^[:blank:]]/p' file | sed '$d'
```

```
Four
  five
  six
```

Alternatively you may use:

```
sed -n '/^Four$/,/^[^[:blank:]]/{/^Four$/p; /^[^[:blank:]]/!p;}' file
```

Answer (score 8):

Use a "do..while()" loop:

```
sed -n '/^Four$/{:a;p;n;/^[[:blank:]]/ba}'
```

details:

```
/^Four$/ {
    :a         # define the label "a"
    p          # print the pattern-space
    n          # load the next line in the pattern space
    /^[[:blank:]]/ba # if the pattern succeeds, go to label "a"
}
```

Comment: This answer is beautiful. Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong tool. sed is for doing s/old/new, that is all. Just use awk:

```
$ awk '/^[^[:blank:]]/{f=/^Four$/} f' file
Four
  five
  six
```

How it works: Every time it finds a line that doesn't start with spaces (`/^[^[:blank:]]/`) it sets a flag `f` (for "found") to 1 if that line starts with `Four` and 0 otherwise (`f=/^Four$/`). Whenever `f` is non-zero that is interpreted as a true condition and so invokes awks default behavior which is to print the current line. So when it hits a block starting with Four it prints every line in that block because `f` is 1/true and for every other block it doesn't print since `f` is 0/false.

Comment: could you explain this a bit more? Very interested to understand how this works

Comment: I added an explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you here.

```
awk '!/^ /{flag=""} /Four/{flag=1} flag'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Four
  five
  six
```

Also in case of you need to save the output into Input_file itself append `> temp_file  && mv temp_file  Input_file` to above code.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -Pzo '\n\KFour\n(\s.+\n)+' input.txt
```

**Output**

```
Four
  five
  six
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^Four/{:a;n;/^\s/ba};d' file
```

If the line begins with `Four` print it and any following lines beginning with a space.

Another way:

```
sed '/^\S/h;G;/^Four/MP;d' file
```

If a line begins with a non-space, copy it to the hold space (HS). Append the HS to each line and if either line begins with `Four` print the first line and delete the rest. This will delete all lines other than the section beginning with `Four`.